# Form1 will not close. (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm practicing some C# and I decided to make an extremely simple login screen. I would like the login screen to close after the password is entered successfully, but I cannot seem to do it.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "pwhere")

        {

            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();

            {

                form2.ShowDialog();
                form1.Close();
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks! :)
This button is in Form1 if that causes any trouble btw.

Fixed it.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "rbxgod")

        {

            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            Hide();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new form and closing it immediately afterwards - that has nothing to do with the existing form

Comment: You should name the forms better, it seems unclear what you want with them. However, as long as `form2` is open (via `.ShowDialog()`) the next line will not execute. Also, you never actually open `form1`, so I am not sure what the point of it is?

Comment: You only show one of your forms and then try to close the other one (the one you didn't show in the first place).  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @UnholySheep Got it. I'll remove that.

Comment: @Sakruh - Please don't post your own answer in the question. Post as an answer. Then your question appear in searches as having an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*This button is in Form1 if that causes any trouble btw.*

Assuming Form1 is your startup form, you can hide it, then call ShowDialog() with Form2, and finally close the original Form allowing the application to exit gracefully:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 f2 = new Form2();  
f2.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

Alternatively, you could wire up the FormClosed() event of Form2 and close the current form from there.  This would allow you to use Show() instead of ShowDialog():

```
this.Hide();
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.FormClosed += (s2, e2) => { this.Close(); };
f2.Show();
```